# h2o failed to connect when called from R: Java version missmatch

Tags: java, r, macos, h2o

`h2o` was working before on my laptop, but I didn't use it for a while 
(and have installed new packages and updated things in the meantime). Yesterday I tried using it, but it didn't work. I erased the `R` `h2o` packaged and I've reinstalled `h2o` from scratch with

```
install.packages("h2o")
```

I tried running `h2o` with `h2o.init()` but it gives me this error

```
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ............................................................ 
[1] "localhost"
[1] 54321
[1] TRUE
[1] -1
[1] "Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused
[1] 7
Error in h2o.init() : H2O failed to start, stopping execution.
```

When I look at the error log it shows

```
Only Java 1.6-1.8 supported, version is 9
```

I tried to look for more info and I think the error is triggered by [this code](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-core/src/main/java/water/H2O.java) on line 1836:

```
if (version != null && !(version.startsWith("1.6") || version.startsWith("1.7") || version.startsWith("1.8"))) {
  System.err.println("Only Java 1.6-1.8 supported, version is " + version);
  return true;
```

So it seems `h2o` is checking for a version that starts with 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 but my version for some reason starts with 9! 
However, on the terminal, `java -version` gives

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.20.0.5-macosx) (build 1.8.0_121-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.20.0.5-macosx) (build 25.121-b15, mixed mode)
```

and `which java` gives

```
/Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin/java
```

------------ EDIT -------

More info: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` gives

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    9, x86_64:  "Java SE 9" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_144, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_51, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_25, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Which explains the `9` that `h2o` is seeing. I find it weird that it expects `1.x.0` but the version is just `9`. In any case, it seems I need to point that `h2o.init()` command to the `1.8` java, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I usually use `brew` to install most things, but I never use `java` so I don't know anything about the versions.

Thanks and best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you reported says:

> Only Java 1.6-1.8 supported, version is 9

Seems like you have Java 9 installed, which is not yet supported by H2O.  Use a compatible version of Java and that will fix the error.

If you can't or don't want to uninstall Java 9, then you'll need to tell H2O which Java you'd like to use by setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.  First, get the location of Java 1.8 by executing the following in a shell:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
```

On my mac, it shows me this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You can check if R can see your `JAVA_HOME` variable by running the following command: `Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")`.

If that's blank (and possibly will be if you're using RStudio), then will have to do a bit more work to get R to see the `JAVA_HOME` variable.  You can edit the `~/.Renviron` file to add `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home` or whatever that location is on your machine. Then restart RStudio and it should work.

Comment: I showed that the `default` java I have is "1.8.0_121". Not sure where R is getting that version 9 (and, note, it seems to read version 9, not 1.9, so I'm wondering if there's an issue there).

Comment: Ok, sorry I missed that the first time around.  I see from your latest edit that you have multiple Javas installed.  Can you [uninstall Java 9](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/remove_olderversions.xml) or update your path to prefer Java 8?

Comment: I changed $JAVA_HOME to point to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home` but the problem persists. I don't know how to change the java that `h2o` wants to call!

Comment: Are you using RStudio instead of command line R?  I've noticed that RStudio doesn't pick up environment variables on occasion.  You can see if R knows about `JAVA_HOME` by checking `Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")`.  If it's blank, try setting it using `Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME")`?  It's a shot in the dark, but might do the trick...

Comment: Yes, that was the key! RStudio, by design, doesn't read the environmental variables from `.bashrc` (no idea what's the reason).
 Please edit your answer to include the following info and I'll accept it :). First, get the location of 1.8 java with `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`. Second, with that location edit `~/.Renviron` and add `JAVA_HOME=your_java_1.8_location`. Restart `RStudio` and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I followed the discussion [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/3vBMiIOhOVs) to get a solution to the problem, though it won't be that convenient for some people.

The default `java` is 1.8.x, hence once that `h2o` can use, but calling `h2o` from `R` results in the version 9 `java` getting called.

The (rather patchy) solution for now is to start the `h2o` server from the terminal like this

```
cd h2o-3.14.0.3   #navigate to wherever you have the h2o installation
java -jar h2o.jar
```

with that running fine, I then link it from `R` without starting an `h2o` instance:

```
h2o.init(startH2O = FALSE)
```

This works fine if you're ok with starting `h2o` from the terminal (might be the only way if you're working on a cluster), but might be annoying if you want to start it from `RStudio` right away.