# Having trouble connecting to H2o server, in R to create a neural network

Tags: r, h2o

I've been having trouble with the H2o package in R lately. What first started out as an update has turned into a mess.

As mentioned, I had to update the H2o package from H2o version 3.16, to the lastest version (3.19). The first issue, was getting H2o to connect with java version 1.8. using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490290/h2o-failed-to-connect-when-called-from-r-java-version-missmatch/46492688#46492688) from a user who had a similar problem, I managed to fix the `/~.Renviron`  and successfully implemented a `Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")`, that way, a link could be created to find the java 1.8 library.

Now I am still getting this error, and I am not sure why.  For some reason the error `Network address/interface is not reachable in 150m` is the most predominate error that keeps repeating. I don't know if this is analogous to the way I set up my `JAVA_HOME` in the `/~.Renviron`. Also the package version is clearly updated.

Here is the full contents of the error:

======================================================================
`> h2o.init(nthreads = -1)`

```
 H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

 Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:


  /var/folders/j5/77z5k0l92kg18q8svpxl_n640000gn/T//RtmpS0HsXx/h2o_andrewlewis_started_from_r.out
/var/folders/j5/77z5k0l92kg18q8svpxl_n640000gn/T//RtmpS0HsXx/h2o_andrewlewis_started_from_r.err

 java version "1.8.0_45"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

 Starting H2O JVM and connecting: 
 ............................................................Cannot load 
 library from path lib/osx_64/libxgboost4j_gpu.dylib
 Cannot load library from path lib/libxgboost4j_gpu.dylib
 Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
 Cannot load library from path lib/osx_64/libxgboost4j_omp.dylib
 Cannot load library from path lib/libxgboost4j_omp.dylib
 Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
 Found XGBoost backend with library: xgboost4j_minimal
 Your system supports only minimal version of XGBoost (no GPUs, no 
 multithreading)!
 ----- H2O started  -----
 Build git branch: master
 Build git hash: d0520285e973c062e57c88c1c865164006358fda
 Build git describe: jenkins-master-4230-2-gd052028
 Build project version: 3.19.0.4231 (latest version: 3.18.0.4)
 Build age: 13 hours and 11 minutes
 Built by: 'jenkins'
 Built on: '2018-03-13 06:31:09'
 Watchdog Build git branch: (unknown)
 Watchdog Build git hash: (unknown)
 Watchdog Build git describe: (unknown)
 Watchdog Build project version: (unknown)
 Watchdog Built by: (unknown)
 Watchdog Built on: (unknown)
 XGBoost Build git branch: (unknown)
 XGBoost Build git hash: (unknown)
 XGBoost Build git describe: (unknown)
 XGBoost Build project version: (unknown)
 XGBoost Built by: (unknown)
 XGBoost Built on: (unknown)
 KrbStandalone Build git branch: (unknown)
 KrbStandalone Build git hash: (unknown)
 KrbStandalone Build git describe: (unknown)
 KrbStandalone Build project version: (unknown)
 KrbStandalone Built by: (unknown)
 KrbStandalone Built on: (unknown)
 Processed H2O arguments: [-name, H2O_started_from_R_andrewlewis_zkx063, -ip, 
 localhost, -port, 54321, -ice_root, 
 /var/folders/j5/77z5k0l92kg18q8svpxl_n640000gn/T//RtmpS0HsXx]
 Java availableProcessors: 4
 Java heap totalMemory: 61.5 MB
 Java heap maxMemory: 910.5 MB
 Java version: Java 1.8.0_45 (from Oracle Corporation)
 JVM launch parameters: [-ea]
 OS version: Mac OS X 10.13.1 (x86_64)
 Machine physical memory: 4.00 GB
 X-h2o-cluster-id: 1520984534744
 User name: 'andrewlewis'
 IPv6 stack selected: false
 Network address/interface is not reachable in 150ms: 
 /fe80:0:0:0:a86b:c976:882a:7803%utun1/name:utun1 (utun1)
 Network address/interface is not reachable in 150ms: 
 /fe80:0:0:0:89dc:1b0f:6ed4:90f9%utun0/name:utun0 (utun0)
 Network address/interface is not reachable in 150ms: 
 /fe80:0:0:0:d093:b2ff:fe8c:74be%awdl0/name:awdl0 (awdl0)
 Network address/interface is not reachable in 150ms: 
 /fe80:0:0:0:10c0:35b:627d:a197%en1/name:en1 (en1)
 Network address/interface is not reachable in 150ms: /192.168.0.9/name:en1 (en1)
 Network address/interface is not reachable in 150ms: 
 /fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0/name:lo0 (lo0)
 Possible IP Address: lo0 (lo0), 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
 Network address/interface is not reachable in 150ms: /127.0.0.1/name:lo0 (lo0)
 IP address not found on this machine 
 [1] "localhost"
 [1] 54321
 [1] TRUE
 [1] -1
 [1] "Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused"
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     
 0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused
 [1] 7
  Error in h2o.init(nthreads = -1) : 
   H2O failed to start, stopping execution.`
```

I do not know what to do from here, I am not sure if other packages need to be updated or if there is a slight change that needs to be implemented for this to work. I'm just trying to get H2o to work.

Comment: First try installing the latest *stable* version, 3.18.0.4 and see if this fixes the issue.  https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/4/index.html You are using a development version.

Comment: Just gave that a shot, and followed the directions line by line. I am still getting the same error.